# try/catch with CURL, Google shortener API?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using the Google Shortener API, and need to handle errors:

https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started#errors

This is my code:

```
public function shorten($url, $extended = false)
{
    # Check buffer
    if ( !$extended && !$this->extended && !empty(self::$buffer[$url]) ) {
        return self::$buffer[$url];
    }

    # Payload
    $data = array( 'longUrl' => $url );
    $data_string = '{ "longUrl": "'.$url.'" }';

    # Set cURL options
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array('Content-Type: application/json'));

    if ( $extended || $this->extended) {
        return json_decode(curl_exec($this->ch));
    } else {
        $ret = json_decode(curl_exec($this->ch))->id;
        self::$buffer[$url] = $ret;
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

But I'm not really sure how to try/catch to grab an error message that Google returns?

Comment: Consider being more specific about your problem. Right now this just looks like "what's wrong with this big block of code?" to most people. What error messages in particular aren't being handled, and what happens as a result of this?

Comment: @someone-or-other The code works. But Google keeps rejecting the URL Shorten requests, and I need to print the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a multidimensional array so you can either loop through the array or a more shothanded method would be to simply check if the error field and code field exists

```
    if ( $extended || $this->extended) {
                $result = json_decode(curl_exec($this->ch));
               if(array_key_exists('errors',$result) && array_key_exists('code',$result)){
                    //handle error
                       }
                    else{
                   //do stuff
                       }

        } else {
                $ret = json_decode(curl_exec($this->ch))->id;
                self::$buffer[$url] = $ret;
                return $ret;
        }
```